# Python Tkinter: Close a window opened by a function not running anymore

Tags: python-2.7, tkinter

Providing I create a Tkinter window using `root = Tk()` into a function and exit the function, how can I then close the window? I'll post an example.

```
def example():
    root = Tk()
    root.update()

print 'opening window'
example()
print 'closing window'
#close window opened by example()?
```

I'd really like it if there was a way to close all opened Tkinter windows.

Comment: `root` is a local variable to `example`, and there's no way to access it unless you return it. When you want to destroy the window, just call `destroy` on the reference returned by `example`. Anyway, you should call `mainloop` on root...

Comment: That's right, thank you. Also, I don't want to call mainloop because I want the program to keep running , the root just gives some additional info. If I call mainloop, the program won't be able to keep running while the window is open.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like with any object, you need a reference to the window in order to close it. Your function should either modify a global variable or return the reference to the caller.

```
def example():
    root = Tk()
    root.update()
    return root

print 'opening window'
window = example()
print 'closing window'
window.destroy()
```

At the end of your question you wrote *"I'd really like it if there was a way to close all opened Tkinter windows."* Since tkinter is designed to only ever have exactly one root window open, this shouldn't be a problem. Just keep track of the one root window that is created. When you destroy it, any children windows will also be destroyed.

Comment: @Axl: maybe, though the example showed only a root window, and that's all we have to go by.

Comment: That worked really well. Thank you. Also, I didn't reffer to toplevel windows.
By the way, I didn't understand something. You say Tkinter is designed to only ever have one root window open. If I do `root = Tk()`, `root.update()`, `rootB = Tk()` and `rootB.update()`, wouldn't this mean I'd have two open windows?

Comment: @ZeroFunter: it means you have two root windows, and they likely won't behave the way you expect. You shouldn't do that. If you need more than one window, create a root window, and then create one or more instances of `Toplevel`.